# Unable to load base64 encoded JPEG2000 string in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg2000

Im trying to load the below string using ImageMagick - However no joy. Any help would be very much appreciated. Here is my sample code.

```
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


$imagedata ="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";

// Decode image from base64
$image=base64_decode($imagedata);

// Create Imagick object
$im = new Imagick();

// Convert image into Imagick
$im->readimageblob($image);

// Decide the type of image file that you need
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');

// Create thumbnail max of 200x82
$im->thumbnailImage(200,82,true);

// Add a subtle border
$color=new ImagickPixel();
$color->setColor("rgb(220,220,220)");
$im->borderImage($color,1,1);

// Output the image
$output = $im->getimageblob();
$outputtype = $im->getFormat();

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

echo $output;
```

Comment: Any error messages? Have you checked (save to file, try to view with your usual image viewer) that what you have decoded is a valid Jpeg2000 file?

Comment: The error message is"The image cannot be displayed because it contains error" . The string that I have with me (base64encoded) is not something that I generated. It's a response that I get from an API call - So I'm assuming it to be valid jpeg2000 encoded string.  I tried decoding it at http://www.convertstring.com/EncodeDecode/Base64Decode . I'm seeing plain text strings.. something like ... "Created by: JJ2000 version 4.1" .. So I'm guessing the string has some meta data that needs to be stripped off before it can work.

Comment: I tried an online base64 image decoder but it failed; probably as it did not have a jpg2000 option. I would try a string from a different source and see if that works - a jpg or png string. Also your header "header('Content-type: image/jpeg');" is for a jpg and not a jpeg2000. Should it be" header('Content-type: image/jp2');"

Comment: Using `echo $yourstring | base64 -d >img.jp2` with both strings yields a proper JPGE200 file it seems (both images are heavily compressed...). So, back to my second suggestion, save to file in you program and 1) compare with a file produced by an external base64 decoder, and 2) try to display the file in an image viewer.

Comment: @Bonzo - Sorry I missed a line of code... which is "$im->setImageFormat('jpeg')".. So my input is a jp2 and the output is jpeg.. Hope this clarifies. It was a good catch BTW.

Comment: @xenoid  - I'm able to successfully echo the decoded string to a file and view it using an image viewer. However this needs to happen via Imagemagick.. ( I will need to increase its resolution and display it)

Comment: So my first milestone would be to have the image displayed as is using Imagemagick

Comment: Okay, I have been able to load the image.. So milestone one achieved.  Thanks for our help

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code..

```
$imagedata ="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";

// Decode image from base64
$image=base64_decode($imagedata);

// Create Imagick object
$im = new Imagick();

// Convert image into Imagick
$im->readimageblob($image);

// Decide the type of image file that you need
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');

// Create thumbnail max of 200x82
$im->thumbnailImage(200,82,true);

// Add a subtle border
$color=new ImagickPixel();
$color->setColor("rgb(220,220,220)");
$im->borderImage($color,1,1);

// Output the image
$output = $im->getimageblob();
$outputtype = $im->getFormat();

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

echo $output;
```